# How to sort vector<vector<int>>?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a vector:

```
vector<vector<int>> myvector;
```

How can I sort this vector in an order as in alphabethical order for strings?

e.g. Output:

Unsorted:

> 5 9 4 12 4
>
> 7 9 3 4 7 9
>
> 6 5 11
>
> 5 8 7 3
>
> 5 9 5 1 1

Sorted:

> 7 9 3 4 7 9
>
> 6 5 11
>
> 5 9 5 1 1
>
> 5 9 4 12 4
>
> 5 8 7 3

Comment: The “sorted” output does *not* appear to be sorted alphabetically (what do you mean by that in the context of numbers anyway? [Lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)?). At best, it’s *inversely* lexicographically ordered.

Comment: I just tried Google "C++ sort". [First hit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) answers the question.

Comment: +1. I'm trusting that the OP realises that with the STL there's often a clear way of doing something which, otherwise, would get you in a tangle. Sometimes it's good to ask, not to try and get into that poor habit of ignoring the STL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the `std::sort` algorithm. The only subtlety is that it sorts in descending order, so you need to change the sorting criteria. Two ways to do this spring to mind.

Use a custom comparison functor, e.g. `std::greater`:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<std::vector<int>>());
```

Use reverse iterators:

```
std::sort(myvector.rbegin(), myvector.rend());
```

The former version makes the intent clearer, whereas the latter may require some head scratching and documentation reading. But the result is the same for both.

Here's a working example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>   // for std::sort
#include <functional>  // for std::greater
#include <iostream>

int main()
{    
  // Set up an example vector
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{{5, 9, 4, 12, 4},
                                  {7, 9, 3, 4, 7, 9},
                                  {6, 5, 11},
                                  {5, 8, 7, 3},
                                  {5, 9, 5, 1, 1}};

  // Perform the sort
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<std::vector<int>>());

  // Output the results
  for (const auto& i : v)
  {
    for (auto j : i)
      std::cout << j << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
7 9 3 4 7 9
6 5 11
5 9 5 1 1
5 9 4 12 4
5 8 7 3
```

Comment: Is there a < operator defined for vectors?

Comment: @Veritas Yes, of course. That is how this works :-)

Comment: Hmm, interesting use of reverse iterators but I have to admit I don’t find this very readable – I would intuitively read this as producing the inverse ordering. Why not use an explicit order relation (`std::greater`) instead?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I wasn't 100% sure that `std::greater` would work out of the box so I went for the sure thing. But it does, so I edited the answer.

Comment: The `<` operator is defined for `vector<int>::iterator` and not for the `actual vector<int>`.

Comment: @Lundin Nonsense. Otherwise this wouldn't work. `std::vector` has all the comparison operators, which do lexicographical comparisons based on the elements of the operands.

Comment: In case anyone is in any doubt that this very elegant answer spills over more than one line, I've edited the worked example.

Comment: @juanchopanza std::sort invokes std::greater, which compares the _items_ of the vector by checking their respective `<` operators. If no such operator is defined for the item's class, you can overload it yourself and then std::sort will work. But for sorting, you don't need to overload `std::vector<item>::operator <`, that's for comparing _vector containers_ with each other, not for comparing individual items.

Comment: @Lundin The items of the vector are vectors. You never need to overload `std::vector<item>::operator <` because a) it is illegal and b) it is already done. As I said, `std::vector` already has these operators.

Comment: @juanchopanza Wow, std::vector has already overloaded the < operator for `MyVerySpecificClassThatIJustCameUpWith`? That's convenient! How did they know that I was about to create that class and how did they predict the correct sorting pattern for it? Damn, computers are so smart nowadays!

Comment: @Lundin: I'm not sure what your confusion is. [`std::vector::operator<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) is provided by the library. Of course the elements must be LessThanComparable.

Comment: @Lundin They guessed that your class would have a suitable `operator<`, or that otherwise you wouldn't be calling `operator<` on a vector of your class. I really don't know what point you are trying to make here. You claimed there is no `operator<` for `std::vector<int>`, and that is complete nonsense.